# Notebook Magnification Shortcut not working

Tags: front-end

Normally I can change the notebook magnification by `ctrl+wheelup/down`, but in Linux it doesn't work anymore. My version is 11.2. My linux distro is fedora 27 and I disabled wayland. What could be the problem?